# Richfaces:same trees in separate windows (or tabs) being in sync?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I have a newbie question in JSF, and particular in Richfaces.

I need my JSF application to have two pages showing the same tree, meaning that:

- The two trees should be showing the same data
- If I change something in one of the trees (i.e. open/close/add a node) the second tree should be automatically updated.

Is this possible? If yes, could you give me a brief outline?

**UPDATE:** Let me give some more details: two of the pages of the application will have this tree in their left pane. The first page will make the second one as a popup when a button is clicked. I want the two pages to show the same tree in sync.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<a4j:push>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf?c=push&tab=usage) to notify your trees about any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for others looking to be sure a part of their page is always up to date, check out the [`ajaxRendered`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/ajaxAttributes.jsf) attribute.